# Take every odd line (1, 3, 5, ...)?

Tags: python, file-io

I need to take every odd line of the following file1 and add a ">" to it.

```
seq1
ACTGTGTGTGTACAGTGCA
seq2
ACTGTGTGTGTACGT
seq3
ACAACACGTGTGTTTTTTT
```

I do the following:

```
file1 = open(sys.argv[1], "r")

counter = 0
for line in file1:
    counter = counter + 1  
    line = line.strip("\n")
    if counter%2 != 0:
        print(">"+line)
    else:
        print(line)

file1.close()
```

This is an exercise, so I wonder if there are better, more pythonic ways of doing the same.

Comment: Your code is clear and readable, you can improve a bit as suggested in the answers. But don't always look for a "Pythonic way". Sometimes forcing comprehension and things might make your code less readable, and people will hate you.

Comment: I agree with @Maroun. Also there's https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ if you're looking for feedback on your code.

Comment: This is better suited on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: [print('>' + v) if i % 2 != 0 else print(v) for i, v in enumerate(file1)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
with open('file1.txt') as f:
    for i,v in enumerate(f,1):
        if i%2!=0:
            print(v) # add '>' like ('>'+v)
```

---

**Output:**

```
seq1

seq2

seq3
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of a more terse way of doing this, but you could make your logic for printing slightly tighter:

```
counter = 0
for line in file1:
    counter = counter + 1  
    if counter%2 != 0:
        print(">", end="")
    print(line.strip("\n"))
```

That is, you always print a line, but for odd lines you also preface with `>`.